# FragmentPagerAdapter not called getItem() method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am creating custom views having Viewpager and custom fragment classes. The issue is my `getItem(int position)` not called. even this is working in another `pagerview`. Please let me know what is wrong with my code.Thanks!!

```
 private void initView(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internal_training_view, this, true);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                ((HFTrainingActivityDashBord)context).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                ((HFTrainingActivityDashBord)context).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                mSectionsPagerAdapterInternal = new SectionsPagerAdapter(((HFTrainingActivityDashBord)context).getSupportFragmentManager());
                mViewPagerInternal = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_hf_training);
                mViewPagerInternal.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
                mViewPagerInternal.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapterInternal);
                TabLayout tabs_hf = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_hf);
                tabs_hf.setupWithViewPager(mViewPagerInternal);

              }        
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

                public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {                       

                    return new IternalTrainingDashBoardFragment(position,context);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // Show 4 total pages.
                    return 4;
                }

                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            return "All";
                        case 1:
                            return "InProgress";
                        case 2:
                            return "Overdue";
                        case 3:
                            return "Not Started";


                    }
                    return null;
                }

            }
```

Comment: why you add `((HFTrainingActivityDashBord)context).getSupportFragmentManager()` in set adapter ? just pass the current class context.

Comment: Its is the current class context . I just cast it to that activity class.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue comes with how you are returning the `fragments` in the `getItem()` method. Use the static `newInstance()` method in your fragment to create the fragment. Not sure if you are to call a fragment using its constructor, rather the `newInstance` factory method Here is an example.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //Note I am using the Fragments static newInstance method(). You arent supposed to call a fragment using new
            return DetailInfoFragment.newInstance(someEntity);
        case 1:
            return DetailContentFragment.newInstance(someEntity);
        case 2:
            return DetailExtraFragment.newInstance(someEntity);
        default:
            return DetailInfoFragment.newInstance(someEntity);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample `newInstance` in my `DetailInfoFragment` class

```
public static DetailInfoFragment newInstance(SomeEntity someEntity) 
{
    DetailInfoFragment fragment = new DetailInfoFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ARG_PARAM1, someEntity);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: The copy of the same code is working fine in other fragments. Actually i am creating three fragments in the one activity . the two are working fine but the one not working. What will be the suspected issue? though I have use FragmentStatePagerAdapter  as well but same was the case